# Save json to a model and db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, rake, rake-task

I am trying to make a custom rake task which searches an artist by name using Itunes API and if it exists it will store the data to a database.

I need 2 things: 1) check if an artist exists (how can I check the respone) and 2) create it with ActiveRecord if it exists.

I don't know how I can implement that, here's how my code looks so far.
Thanks in advance.

```
require 'net/http'
require 'json'

  task :artist,[""] do |t, args|
    request = ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term => "#{args}")
    puts request
  end
```

Comment: What does the response look like? What exactly is in an Artist model?

Comment: I gather you want to use https://github.com/rlivsey/itunes-search-api. This gem has not been updated in 3 years, so I don't think it will work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, don't use the word request, it's a reserved word and could cause  you problems.  You might try `result` instead.

If there is nothing found, you'll get an empty array back.

So you'll just need to check for

```
result.empty?
```

The search is pretty straight forward if it's based on artist name

```
unless Artist.exists?(name: result[0]["artistName"])
  Artist.create(name: result[0]["artistName", itunes_id: result[0]["artistId"])
end
```

Because Apple uses a matching algorithm, it's always possible your result set can return more than one entry, I would double check that it's the one you want first.

Comment: Thank you so much, it always seems so easy when you see the correct answer :]

Answer (score 0):

> 1) check if an artist exists (how can I check the respone)

```
request = ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term => "#{args}")
puts request
```

It will depend on the contents of request or how `ITunesSearchAPI.search` method behaves when there is no artist on iTunes. Usually, APIs return an empty array in JSON. So, you can simply check if a result array is empty.

```
# Provided request['artists'] is an array
if request['artists'].empty?
    # no artists
else
    # there are artists
end
```

While we're on it, you don't have to interpolate your `args`, just print them out or use `.to_s` method if you want to convert it into `String`.

```
ITunesSearchAPI.search(:term => args.to_s)
```

---

> 2) create it with ActiveRecord if it exists.

You can use ActiveRecord without Rails. It has been [covered many times](https://www.google.com/search?q=ActiveRecord%20without%20rails). It boils down to installing the active_record gem, including it, establishing a connection and inheriting from `ActiveRecord::Base`.

```
require 'active_record'
require 'sqlite3'
require 'logger'

ActiveRecord::Base.logger = Logger.new('db.log')
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
  adapter: 'sqlite3',
  database: 'db/mydb.sqlite3',
  timeout: 5000,
  pool: 5
)

class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply. Good to know about interpolation.

Comment: @r0uder, consider upvoting answers as a way of saying "thank you" on SO )